# pandas join two dataframe based on Index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to join two dataframes based on Index values of dataframes however, my result produces NaN and followed by values with index values repeated.

```
print st
```

results in (stored in data frame series and with only index as follows)

```
index
1499054400000
1499140800000
1499227200000
1499313600000
1499400000000
```

Another dataframe is as follows

```
print dtest2
```

This results in (same index as above)

```
                1
index   
1499227200000   33.48
1499400000000   35.71
```

I am trying to get the following when i merge two dataframes

***Result desired***

```
index            1
1499054400000    0.0
1499140800000    0.0
1499227200000    33.48
1499313600000    0.0
1499400000000    35.71
```

However when i concatenate as follows

```
pd.concat([st,dtest2],ignore_index=False)
```

I get the following

```
                1
index   
1499054400000   NaN
1499140800000   NaN
1499227200000   NaN
1499313600000   NaN
1499400000000   NaN
1499227200000   33.48
1499400000000   35.71
```

Comment: Don't use concat; you're essentially doing a union of the two DataFrames. Use `pd.DataFrame.join` to join on indices like so `st.join(dtest)`. That will inner join your DataFrames by default; you can use the `how=` parameter to the method to change the join to left, right, or outer.

Comment: I did try join and different variants of it too , for example st.join(detest2,how='inner') produces empty frame and st.join(detest2,how='right') produces only two rows with values and no other row is displayed. I also tried other vairants but no success :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC... use `pd.DataFrame.reindex`

```
dtest2.reindex(st.index, fill_value=0)

                   1
index               
1499054400000   0.00
1499140800000   0.00
1499227200000  33.48
1499313600000   0.00
1499400000000  35.71
```

---

However, you may have a hidden problem in that the types are not the same.  You can ensure that all indices are the same by using `astype` to cast them.

```
dtest2.index = dtest2.index.astype(str)
st.index = st.index.astype(str)

dtest2.reindex(st.index, fill_value=0)

                   1
index               
1499054400000   0.00
1499140800000   0.00
1499227200000  33.48
1499313600000   0.00
1499400000000  35.71
```

---

Or

```
dtest2.index = dtest2.index.astype(int)
st.index = st.index.astype(int)

dtest2.reindex(st.index, fill_value=0)

                   1
index               
1499054400000   0.00
1499140800000   0.00
1499227200000  33.48
1499313600000   0.00
1499400000000  35.71
```

Comment: dtest2.reindex(st.index, fill_value=0) produces blank dataframe with zeros in first column. Hence it is not working and hence no joy:(

Comment: @user2560244 easy fix... one moment.

Comment: sure ... looking forward to it

Comment: @user2560244 glad I could help... if you could do me a favor.  The other answers are accurate as well, could you give them an up-vote to show your appreciation for helping out?  Thx

Answer (score 3):

use the merge function instead of concat

```
pd.merge(st,dtest2,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True).fillna(0)
```

Comment: This produces duplicate index values and hence no joy :( as the problem remains same. I do not want duplicate index entries and struggling to achieve it

Comment: This is accurate but doesn't address the issue OP had in that the index types were different.  Had they been the same, this works perfect.  Assuming indices are unique.  I'd stick with `how='left'`

Comment: @piRSquared nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
result = st.join(dtest2, how='outer').fillna(0)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
                   1
  index               
  1499054400000   0.00
  1499140800000   0.00
  1499227200000  33.48
  1499313600000   0.00
  1499400000000  35.71
```

Or, `left` join would also give same result:

```
result = st.join(dtest2, how='left').fillna(0)
```

Comment: This is accurate but doesn't address the issue OP had in that the index types were different.  Had they been the same, this works perfect.  Assuming indices are unique.

Comment: Agreed with piRSquared. Unfortunately Index types were different and hence my struggle.... But thank you @open-source for your time and suggestion.

Comment: @piRSquared, sorry! I missed that part. and thanks, I learnt how to handle such cases :) +1 for the answer.